# How to check if a date (dd/mm/yyyy) has been submitted?

Tags: sql, symfony, filter

I have a filter bar where you can search with names, and vehicule brand but I wanted to know how to actually check with dates in this format -> `dd/mm/yyyy` as right know nothing happens when I search a date, I receive a blank page without errors, but just zero results.

I found maybe a solution using this `$fullDate  = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$filter);` but i have a struggle where to add it in my code.

So I will share you my code and what I researched

**The query where you can see all queries with the filter arguments (for my search)**

```
public function getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, User $user, $archive, $filter)
    {

        $fullDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $filter);
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("opn");

        $or = new Orx();

        if($fullDate !== false) {
            $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.dateCreation', ':filter'));
        } else {
            $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.id', ':filter'));
            $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.vehiculeMarque', ':filter'));
            $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.clientNom', ':filter'));
            $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.clientPrenom', ':filter'));
        }

        $or->addMultiple($textFilters);
        $qb->andWhere($or);

        $query = $qb
            ->andWhere("opn.type = :type")
            ->andWhere("opn.resellerId = :reseller")
            ->andWhere("opn.archive = :archive")
            ->setParameters([
                "type" => $type,
                "reseller" => $user->getId(),
                'archive' => $archive,
                'filter' => '%' . $filter . '%'
            ])
            ->orderBy("opn.dateCreation", "DESC")
            ->getQuery()
        ;

        return $query;
    }
```

This is what it shows me in my query profiler when I do a date search in this format `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
SELECT 
  count(r0_.id) AS sclr0 
FROM 
  reseller_operation r0_ 
WHERE 
  r0_.dateCreation LIKE ? 
  AND r0_.type = ? 
  AND r0_.reseller_id = ? 
  AND r0_.archive = ?
```

So right now at that moment this code work in a way that when I do a dump `dump($fullDate)` it shows false when I don't enter a date, and shows the date when I do. So I guess that does work at the moment.
The problem i still have is that it doesn't show any results, just a blank page with zero results.

I don't know if you need my controller or my twig to get a better picture? I didn't put them in here because I thought this wouldn't be necessary, but feel free to ask me.

Comment: What is the issue you have? Please be accurate about the problem.

Comment: Hi @Jeet currently I have a filter bar where I can search by names and such (with my query) but when I enter a date format like this `**/**/****` it doesn't search in this format. i wanted to know how can I do that. Sorry for the fuzzy problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I succeeded in making that work. Here is the code.

```
public function getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, User $user, $archive, $filter)
    {

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("opn");

        $fullDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat( "d/m/Y", $filter);


        $or = new Orx();

        if($fullDate !== false) {
            $fullDate = $fullDate->format('Y-m-d');
            $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.dateCreation', ':date'));
        }

        $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.id', ':filter'));
        $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.vehiculeMarque', ':filter'));
        $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.clientNom', ':filter'));
        $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.clientPrenom', ':filter'));

        $or->addMultiple($textFilters);
        $qb->andWhere($or)
            ->andWhere("opn.type = :type")
            ->andWhere("opn.resellerId = :reseller")
            ->andWhere("opn.archive = :archive")
            ->setParameters([
                "type" => $type,
                "reseller" => $user->getId(),
                'archive' => $archive,
                'filter' => '%' . $filter . '%'
            ])
            ->orderBy("opn.dateCreation", "DESC");

        if ($fullDate) {
            $qb->setParameter('date','%'. $fullDate .'%');
        }

        return $qb->getQuery();
    }
```

Hope that helps some in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

You are doing fine. In your `Repository`, you can check if `filter` is a date time or a string and design your query accordingly.

`createFromFormat` will return false, If it doesn't get a correct date format from the string provided, we can take advantage from it.

I have edited your code from what I understand :

```
 public function getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, User $user, $archive, $filter)
{
    $fullDate  = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$filter);


    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("opn");

    $or = new Orx();

    $params = [
        "type" => $type,
        "reseller" => $user->getId(),
        'archive' => $archive,
        'filter' => '%' . $filter . '%'
    ];

    // Filter date only if the filter is a valid date.
    if ($fullDate !== false) {
        $date = $fullDate->format('Y-m-d');
        $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->andX($qb->expr()->eq('opn.dateCreation', ':date_filter'));
        $params['date_filter'] = $date;
    }
    else {
        // Filter considerting filter as a name or anything else.
        $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.id', ':filter'));
        $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.vehiculeMarque', ':filter'));
        $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.clientNom', ':filter'));
        $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.clientPrenom', ':filter'));
    }

    $or->addMultiple($textFilters);
    $qb->andWhere($or);

    $query = $qb
        ->andWhere("opn.type = :type")
        ->andWhere("opn.resellerId = :reseller")
        ->andWhere("opn.archive = :archive")
        ->setParameters($params)
        ->orderBy("opn.dateCreation", "DESC")
        ->getQuery()
    ;

    return $query;
}
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. but this actually doesn't work as it shows no results. I am on symfony 2.3, maybe its a problem? Actually  I thought I could do the trick in the controller.
Also the `use` that is in my query is `use DateTime;` don't know if its the correct one or if it helps

Comment: Symfony 2.3 query might be different. But logic is same. I guess you have to edit with `->like` for date condition. you don't have to `use DateTime` You can just have a `\DateTime::` as its defined in core PHP not any other 3rd party library.

Comment: I've edited my answer to handle `equal` condition instead of `like` for date filter. Please have it checked. You need to debug any query related errors.

Comment: I added `\DateTime as you asked, but yeah still no results. It refresh the page but nothing show :/ I don't know what does not work.

Comment: I don't know if its the right one, does it look like it? 

`SELECT 
  count(r0_.id) AS sclr0 
FROM 
  reseller_operation r0_ 
WHERE 
  r0_.dateCreation = ? 
  AND r0_.type = ? 
  AND r0_.reseller_id = ? 
  AND r0_.archive = ?`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154870/discussion-between-jeet-and-chicken-burger).